# Installing Mercurial 1.4.3 - Python Requirement?

Tags: python, mercurial

Is it ok if I install Python 2.6.4 instead of the 2.4 requirement listed on the [Mercurial website](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)?

I'm fairly new to Mercurial and Python. My general impression of Python is that newer versions break compatibility with older versions.

If Python is currently at 2.6.4 and Mercurial 1.4.3 lists Python 2.4 as a requirement, maybe they are strictly limiting to Python 2.4 only?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with 2.6.4.  Be aware, though, that Python 3 is a different animal.  In general unless a package states that it works with Python 3, assume it won't.

Comment: Your general impression of Python is mistaken, somewhat sadly (it would be a very bad thing were it true). Python is only slightly more backwards incompatible than it has to be given its featureset (e.g. adding a new builtin is always backwards-incompatible, since code could, at least in theory, rely on said builtin not existing). Python 3 is the exception, not the rule (and the changes are so much that a language freeze has been implemented so that Python doesn't get ahead of its implementers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.4 is a minimum requirement. 2.6.4 is fine.